# Add dll in MSIX windows build in flutter

Tags: flutter, windows, build, flutter-dependencies, msix

I'm trying to build my flutter app in MSIX, but when i install, it opens a white screen.

After some search i found out that this is happening because the build does not include the sqlite3.dll.

I searched over stack overflow to try to find some solution, but all the answers were outdated or when i tried to implement them, it didn't work.

Is there any way to add the dll file into the MSIX windows build?